# Своя разметка для ListView

Tags: java, android

Хотел сделать свою разметку для `ListView`, а именно добавить кнопки в элементы списка. Сделал так: в layout создал файл listview.xml с содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/listView">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/text1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_share"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_white"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Далее в коде прописал следующее:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview, rusArr);
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.test.proj2, PID: 3761
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:388)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362) 
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970) 
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704) 
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765) 
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744) 
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301) 
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871) 
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683) 
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619) 
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании `ArrayAdapter`, файл разметки, указанный вторым аргументом конструктора, должен состоять только из одного `TextView`.

Если у вас как-то свой файл разметки для элемента `ListView`, то Вам нужно создавать свой адаптер. Подробнее про это можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html).

А вообще, я бы порекомендовал вместо `ListView` использовать `RecyclerView`, ибо он более гибкий (именно он пришел на замену `ListView`).

Comment: А для моего случая как быть? чтобы кнопки тоже были

Comment: @Михаил, Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. А такой вопрос. для android версии 4.0.3 будет ли работать RecyclerView?

Comment: @Михаил, `RecyclerView` находится в библиотеке поддержки `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`, как видно из ее названия, она может использоваться начиная с 7-ой версии API, то есть с Android 2.1.